# Change Port 53 WSL2

Tags: docker, port, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I run a DNS Server (port 53) on my machine and I also use Docker, but the new docker update forces the usage of WSL instead of Hyper-V.

The problem is, WSL2 needs ports 53 in order to function. So now I have a port conflict. Is there any way to change the port WSL uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was a Windows Service which used the port 53 called SharedAccess.

You can stop it by doing this command `net stop sharedaccess`
And permanently disabling it by going into services.msc (The Internet Connection Sharing (ICS))

More info can be found from this article:
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/your-computer-is-not-a-black-box-understanding-processes-and-ports-on-windows-by-exploring

Comment: This may save some time: you might have to stop the "Host Network Service" first ("Сетевая служба узла" in Russian). In my case ICS was refusing to stop without this.